# Exact return point of yield in python generators

Tags: python, generator

In a quest to teach myself Python generators, especially their `send()` method, I wanted to write a toy example that would allow me calculate an "interruptible" Fibonacci sequence.

Eventually I succeeded, but I don't understand exactly what is going on.  Consider these two examples.

#### Successful example:

```
def genFib(a=0, b=1):
    while True:
        c = yield a+b
        if c:
            a, b = b, c
        else:
            a, b = b, a+b
    return
​
fib_number = genFib()
​
print fib_number.next()
print fib_number.next()
print fib_number.next()
print fib_number.next()
print fib_number.next()
print fib_number.send(100)
print fib_number.next()
print fib_number.next()
​
1
2
3
5
8
105
205
310
```

#### Failure that I thought would work:

```
def genFib(a=0, b=1):
    while True:
        c = yield a+b
        a, b = b, c
    return
​
fib_number = genFib()
​
print fib_number.next()
print fib_number.next()
1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-4513153ea517> in <module>()
      8 
      9 print fib_number.next()
---> 10 print fib_number.next()

<ipython-input-59-4513153ea517> in genFib(a, b)
      1 def genFib(a=0, b=1):
      2     while True:
----> 3         c = yield a+b
      4         a, b = b, c
      5     return

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

**Why does the second example not work?** In particular, the second example seems assign a value of `None` to `c` in all *but the first* executions of the generator.  Why?  How does it know to assign to `c` the first time `next()` is called, but not the next `next()` time?

My understanding was that generators resume execution (when they are called again) beginning on the line *after* the yield line, but my example has me thinking this is wrong, at least in some cases.  Where exactly does execution resume from?  Does it re-execute the `yield` line but this time with somehow leaving off everything after the `yield`?  How does `c` get assigned to `None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yield` is a bit of a strange expression.  Execution pauses at the `yield` after the right-hand side is evaluated, but before the assignment takes place.

The value that is returned in the `yield` statement is whatever you `.send` to the generator.  Since you are calling `.next` rather than `.send`, the value returned from the yield expression (`c`) is `None`.  In the first example, that's fine since `c` is checked for truthiness and then is not used if it is falsy (e.g. `None`).  However, in the second example, `c` isn't checked so you end up adding `None` to an integer (which obviously doesn't produce desirable results).